# Unescaping " In PHP Dynamically

Tags: php

There is a page that I'm currently working on (http://www.flcbranson.org/freedownloads-new.php) that loads data from an rss feed.

That rss feed contains descriptions, some of which contain quotation marks.

When the page is displayed (you can click on the Read Summary link for Filled With All The Fullness Of God to see what I'm talking about), it does \" for each quote.

I assume that it's because of php's escaping requirements.

Is there a way that I can remove the escape character (other than the obvious "remove the quotation marks")?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: Unless i'm misreading your question, are you talking about just unescaping the quotes 'n stuff? http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you have magic quotes turned on.  Read the [PHP documentation for stripslashes()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) and pay special attention to the magic quotes stuff.

In a nutshell, if you know that your working with a string and not (say) an array, you can do the following:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_runtime()) {
    $string = stripslashes($string);
}
```

If the data is coming from `$_GET`, `$_POST`, or `$_COOKIE` superglobals, use this instead:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $string = stripslashes($string);
}
```

If it's not a string you're dealing with, you may need to look at the `stripslashes_deep()` implementation in the PHP docs.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the slashes by running data through:
[stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

However, you still want to make your output (if you are doing something with this) HTML safe.
so run this function on the data after:
[htmlspecialchars()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Answer (score 2):

try using stripslashes()

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Answer (score 2):

checkout [stripslashes()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)